# Check MySQL if token is valid, then return. If not, generate token

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, validation, token

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_tokens (
   ID int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   USER varchar(128) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User name',
   TS timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   IP varchar(64) NOT NULL,
   TOKEN varchar(128) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Hashed tokens',
   VALID (12),
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) 
)
```

And I want to check if a token exists for a user. If it exists, then it should return the token. If not, it should generate one.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
  global $wpdb;
  global $user_login;
  $token = uniqid();
  $hashedtoken = md5($token);
  $user = $user_login;
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $valid = "1";
  $chkdb = mysql_query("SELECT valid FROM wp_tokens WHERE user=$user");

if(mysql_num_rows($chkdb) == 1)
{
    echo $hashedtoken;
}
else
    {
     $wpdb->insert('wp_tokens', 
     array('user' => $user, 'token' => $hashedtoken, 'ip' => $ip, 'valid' => $valid),
     array('%s','%s','%s'));    
    }
?>
```

It doesn't work and I cannot solve. It's being executed on Wordpress $wpdb should be working. Please help!

Comment: User = User ID ? User Name? If it is a string, use '$user' instead of $user in the query.

Comment: Okay that fixed my error but it is still generating a new token whenever the page is refreshed =\

Comment: What do you mean by generating token? Where the code processed? in IF condition or in ELSE condition?

Comment: It seems to be returning $hashedtoken on ELSE. I added echo $hashedtoken; because I realized that it wasn't displaying anything for ELSE. I think the problem may be that it's not fetching the existing token. And then simply generating a new one (and on a new line in the database). If that makes sense.

Comment: Yea, since you used if else statement, the result should be either one. So it may caused by your SQL command. Try your command in phpMyAdmin or echo `mysql_num_rows($chkdb)` to see the output then you may know where the token came out.

Comment: Alright cool so `mysql_num_rows($chkdb)` is displaying the ID, I think because I set as to PRIMARY KEY in MySQL, and is not being changed on page refresh. Here is where I'm at now:

`if(mysql_num_rows($chkdb) == $valid)

{

    echo mysql_num_rows($chkdb);

}

else

    {

     $wpdb->insert('wp_tokens', 

     array('user' => $user, 'token' => $hashedtoken, 'ip' => $ip, 'valid' => $valid),

     array('%s','%s','%s'));

    }`

Comment: Have you properly setup your table? I saw `value (12)` and there is no datatype. Maybe you should give the column a datatype. When I setup the table with your structure provided didn't work.

Comment: Actually that is a good question. The VALID field should be either 1 or 0 for true or false ideally. That way we could check from PHP if the row is valid or not and then display. Am I correct here?

Comment: No, that's incorrect. "Exists" and "Valid" are two different stories. To check if a token exists or not, you can use `mysql_num_rows`. But if you want to check it is valid or not, you have to use `mysql_result($query, 0)` to get it because it could return 0 in result even if the row exists.

Comment: I see. How would I use `mysql_num_rows` to fetch the token?

Comment: No, if you want to return the token itself, you shouldn't use `mysql_num_rows` because it only returns how many rows in the result, not the data. If you want to fetch data, you can use `mysql_result` (it could only return the data of single column) or `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I suppose what I need to do is first check if there is a token, then check if it's valid, then if it is valid return the token. If it's not valid it would generate a new token then return. To invalidate the token would be a reset function. I hope that made sense.

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense.